# Align text to center with background color only for text

Tags: html, css

How can I align a text to center of the screen with the background of the link to be blue. Without altering the HTML code and altering only CSS code.
I am using Display Inline and Align Text: Center but it is not working.
In the Link Part I want to align it to the Center top and should be fixed.

https://notepad.pw/css1234 (for css file)

https://notepad.pw/html1234 (for html file)

Comment: by provindg us the html and css code

Comment: It'd help if you posted the relevant bit of HTML in your question so we could know for sure that any possible answers would actually work. If possible, you could just change `display: inline` to `display: block`. If you use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`, the element will only be as wide as it needs to be to fit its text, so centering the text in that element won't do much because there won't be any extra space on either side of the text to center things.

Comment: Can you show us what HTML you have so we know what to reference for your example?

Answer (score 2):

## What You Want

- Align a text to center of the screen with the background of the link to be blue
- Altering only CSS code
- Link should be center top aligned and fixed

### Modification

- Add `text-align: center;` in `body{}`
- Remove `width: 100%;`

#### Explanation

- This will center align `p` in center of `body`
- By removing `width: 100%`, the background color will only fit the content (which is the link in this case).

**Please run the code below to see if this is what you asked.**

```css
/* This is a partial blocks.css, you need to add more rules
   to this file to complete the assignment.  Do not add any CSS
   styling to the original index.htm / start.htm */

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
}

/* Here is one of many  CSS rules you will need... */
#three{
    position: fixed;
    border: 5px solid #fea405;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 25%;
    top: 0;
}
#two{
 position: fixed;
    border: 5px solid #048103;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 25%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#four{
 position: fixed;
 border: 5px solid #ffff00;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 25%;
 bottom: 0;
}
#one{
 position: fixed;
 border: 5px solid #0201ff;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 25%;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#link
{ 
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 background-color:#0201ff;
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blocks</title>
  <!-- Do not change this file - add your CSS styling 
       rules to the blocks.css file included below -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">
Turns out you have a really fun time if you 
go to work every day and focus on being 
silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
</div>
<div id="two">
All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence, 
and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
</div>
<div id="three">
Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters 
fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never 
mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
</div>
<div id="four">
Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events;
small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
</div>
<p id="link">
<a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
Brainy Quote
</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
<style>
div
{
text-align:center; 
background-color:red;
}

.linkFrame
{
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: blue;
width:20%;
height: 100%;
}
.linkFrame a
{
color: white;
}
</style>
```

html:

```
<div><div class="linkFrame"><a href="#">YourText</a></div></div>
```

Tryit Editor link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPYX1DG3O9GQ

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your little css code which is written for **#link** with below code:

```
#link{
   text-align: center;
}
#link a{
   background-color:#0201ff;
   color: white;
}
```

[Refer the code with ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ti0r.png)